# Gunicorn | Selenium - Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, virtualenv, gunicorn

I am having issues running selenium headless with the firefox geckodriver through the systemd service file i have created. I know selenium headless is working, because i can activate the virtualenv and run the python script without any issues.
I have tested it without running it through a virtualenv and it works fine.

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

This is the error i get, logs from gunicorn:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

The geckodriver log doesnt throw any errors.

What could i be doing wrong? To me it seems the virtualenv cant find firefox.

It could be related to the config of the systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Meta: when using the markdown link formatting you used, the main bracket contains the text and the hidden one contains the URL. Meaning `[visible text][1] ... [1]: https://example.com`, not the other way around. I edited to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Well i figured it out eventually haha.

All you need to do is add the following to **/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service**

> Environment="PATH=/usr/bin"

Comment: Finally, I've been trying to fix this for two days! Thanks.